# "Don't show a half-built house to a fool." - German proverb?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, proverb

George Polya claims in his book *Mathematical Discovery on Understanding, Learning and Teaching Problem Solving* [1]:

> There is a German proverb: "Don't show a half-built house to a fool." (p. xii)

It might roughly translate to

> Zeige einem Idioten kein halb-gebautes Haus.

or similar. I admit that translation itself is very non-idiomatic and frankly, it has me stumped. I understand its meaning, but 
I myself am German and I have never heard of such a proverb. A discussion with colleagues and a Google search for likely translations did not turn up anything. Has anybody heard of such a proverb and could shed any light on what original proverb Polya had in mind?

---

George Polya sagt in seinem Buch *Mathematical Discovery on Understanding, Learning and Teaching Problem Solving* [1]:

> There is a German proverb: "Don't show a half-built house to a fool." (p. xii)

Man könnte es grob mit

> Zeige einem Idioten kein halb-gebautes Haus.

übersetzen. Das ist zugegebenermaßen sehr unidiomatisch, aber ich kann mir nicht zusammenreimen was das ursprüngliche Sprichwort gewesen sein soll. Ich verstehe was das Sprichwort ausdrücken will, aber ich bin selbst deutsch und habe von so einem Sprichwort noch nie gehört. Eine kurze Umfrage unter Bekannten sowie eine Google Suche nach möglichen Übersetzungen hat keine Treffer geliefert. Kennt jemand das Sprichwort oder hat jemand eine Ahnung, worauf Polya sich hier beziehen könnte?

[1] Polya, George. Mathematical Discovery on Understanding, Learning and Teaching Problem Solving, Combined Volumes I and II. Wiley, 1981. http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471089753.html.

Comment: Auf Google finde ich, wenn ich nach dem englischen Satz suche, nur diese Seite, den Text von Polya und rumänische Foreneinträge auf www.price.ro aus den Jahren 2003 und 2004, bei denen der Autor (er nennt sich »señor«) diesen englischen Satz als Signatur verwendet hat. Daher vermute ich 1., dass Polya sich bezüglich der Herkunft des Sprichwortes geirrt hat, und 2., dass das Original-Sprichwort rumänisch ist.

Comment: [Pólya](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Pólya) ist in Budapest zu KuK-Zeiten aufgewachsen und hat längere Zeit auch in der Schweiz gelebt. Wenn es nicht schon eine gut belegte Antwort gäbe, hätte ich auf einen ungarischen Ursprung getippt.

Comment: Ich bin Muttersprachler und eigentlich mit Sprichwörtern ganz gut - aber das habe ich noch nie gehört.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bei [Wanders Sprichwörterlexikon](http://www.zeno.org/Wander-1867/A/Narr?hl=haus%20narr) habe ich nur gefunden:

> Man darf einem Narren kein ungebautes Haus weisen. – Bohemia, 1872, Nr. 3.

Begegnet ist mir dieses oder ein ähnliches Sprichwort noch nie.

Answer (score 14):

Gemeint sein könnte

> Man muss keinem Narren eine halbfertige Arbeit zeigen.

Das ist die Nummer 7411 aus der Sammlung "Die deutschen Sprichwörter" von [Karl Simrock](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Simrock) von 1846. Auf archive.org gibt es ein [Digitalisat](https://archive.org/details/diedeutschenspr00simrgoog), dort findet sich die Nummer 7411 auf Seite 348. Besser zu lesen ist die [Ausgabe im Projekt Gutenberg](http://lueersen.homedns.org/!gutenb/simrock/sprichwt/sprichwt.htm), dort in [diesem Abschnitt](http://lueersen.homedns.org/!gutenb/simrock/sprichwt/sprichn1.htm).

Am Rande, im Finnischen gibt es laut der [finnischen Botschaft](http://www.finnland.de/public/default.aspx?contentid=217296&nodeid=37059&contentlan=33&culture=de-DE) das Sprichwort

> Herroille ja hulluile ei pidä näyttää keskeneräistä työtä.

übersetzt

> Herren und Narren soll man keine halbfertige Arbeit zeigen.

Die Erkenntnis scheint also nicht auf das Deutschland Mitte des 19. Jahrhunderts beschränkt zu sein ;)

Woher in der englischen Fassung die Einschränkung von "Arbeit" auf speziell "Haus" kommt, kann ich allerdings auch nicht sagen.